# Unable to subscribe to topic in web using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to subscribe to topic in login function, I get the device token and push it into array named **tokens**

And I use fcm function to subscribe, First :
import fcm and intialize a new fcm with my server_key :

```
var FCM = require("fcm-node");
let fcm = new FCM(process.env.SERVER_KEY);
```

Then use this function to subscribe to topic

```
const tokens = [];

// deviceToken it contain my device Token
tokens.push(deviceToken);

fcm.subscribeToTopic({ deviceToken: tokens }, { topicName: "general" })
   .then((resposne) => {console.log(resposne)})
   .catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
```

It return in terminal:

```
 CB(err, res);
                ^

TypeError: CB is not a function
```

and i try to change the function to :

```
fcm.subscribeToTopic(deviceToken, "cars", (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("subscribeToTopicError:", err);
    } else {
      console.log("subscribeToTopicResponse:", response);
    }
  });
```

it return `{ statusCode: 400, message: 'Bad Request' }`

**How can i subscribe to topic with nodejs ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone meet this problem in the future the problem because the "fcm-node" It has no support since about 2017!

You can use "firebase-admin" Instead of that, Then you will not meet such this problem.